# Raspberry pi 3 crontab doens't work without log

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, startup

I already found a lot of posts with crontab errors but i still can't figure out where is my issu.

I want to start a python script on `/home/pi/somedir/main.py` and to fix any relative path issu in my script i made a `start.sh` next to it  containing

```
cd /home/pi/somedir
/usr/bin/python3.7 main.py
```

I made it executable with `sudo chmod -x start.sh` and it works find went i do `/home/pi/somedir/start.sh` manually, but i want to autostart it at start.

I tried multiple ways (like `/etc/rc.local`) and it never worked. As crontab seems to be the better way to do this, i tried `crontab -e` (the crontab for the `pi` user so) and i added

```
@reboot bash /home/pi/somedir/start.sh > /home/pi/somedir/logstart.txt &
```

to have the logs and to execute the script without blocking the rest of the system. But the script doesn't start and there is nothing in the log file.

The script is a python3 discord bot with logging output, running just find when launched manually. It is a raspberry pi 3B+, with a fresh install of raspberry pi os desktop and i have nothing else running on it.

Thanks for any help and sorry if my english is not correct !

ps: If you know better options to host python3 scripts like discord bots on raspberry pi it would also be usefull of course, i am clearly a beginner !

Comment: Try adding #!/bin/sh to your script head and then using this
@reboot /home/pi/somedir/start.sh > /home/pi/somedir/logstart.txt &

Comment: If you don't wanna have to reboot to test it, replace @reboot with "* * * * *" without the quotes to have it run every minute.

Comment: The script still doesn't start and no log :/ Thanks for the testing tips !

Comment: Oh actually the script now start after some times, so it seems to be a issu only at start. Any way of delaying the start of the script ? Or the "* * * * *" argument is ok for general usage ? Does it restart the script every time or only if the script is not actually running ?

Comment: The "@reboot" actually runs the script before the machine is fully booted on. I don't know about on Pi but on my laptop running ubuntu, "@reboot" fires before I even see the login screen. The run every minute script should start an entirely new process every time it fires. Here's a good link to setting it to run how you want rather than every minute.

https://crontab.tech/

Comment: Perhaps instead of boot, you can make it at a specific hour every morning around the time you boot it up.

Comment: Ok it seems to be a good solution for me, thank you for your answers ! Have a good day

Comment: `chmod -x` *removes* executable access. (Read access is sufficient if you run it with `bash start.sh` though.)

Answer (score 1):

The issu was that the script won't start at reboot as it is before the system is fully booted. One solution was to start the process at precise hour when the system is fully start, like every morning. An other would be to add a delay before running the start.sh script, somethings like

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/pi/somedir/start.sh > /home/pi/somedir/logstart.txt &
```

works for me aswell.